# Filter rows of a dataframe based on presence of specific character '+' in the column

Tags: python

I have data frame like this:

```
id : Name 
0  : one
1  : one + two
2  : two
3  : two + three + four
```

I want to filter rows from this dataframe where name contains '+' and save it to another dataframe. I tried:

```
df[df.Name.str.contains("+")]
```

but i'm gettin error:

```
nothting to repeat at position 0
```

Any help would be appreciated...Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) of the `str.contains` method, it assumes that the string you are passing is a regexp by default.

Therefore, you can either escape the plus character: `"\+"` or pass the argument `regex=False` to the method:

- `df[df.Name.str.contains("\+")]`
- `df[df.Name.str.contains("+", regex=False)]`

Comment: Thanks for the help.... if its not too much to ask how can i subset the dataframe which does not contains '+'... I would really appreciate the help and it can save my day...

Comment: please don't bother, I got it.... I just have to put ~ to negate the condition